# Escaping parentheses in bash/sed

Tags: bash, sed

I've got some issues with escaping parentheses in a string, using bash and sed.

Here's what I'm doing:

```
#!/bin/bash 
olddescription='(1 phrase/line)'
newdescription="\"$volledigenaam\""
(cd /home/hew/git/odoo/addons/$technischenaam ; sed -i s/$olddescription/$newdescription/g __openerp__.py)
```

I've read that if I use single quotes, I don't need to escape the parentheses.
I also tried escaping the parentheses with backslash but didn't work either.

This is the error:

> sed: -e expression #1, char 4: unterminated `s' command

Any ideas on how to solve this?

Comment: The single quotes are not part of the variable value so have no effect in the sed command. Try adding a "set -x" at the beginning and you should see how things get expanded.

Comment: BTW, [BashFAQ #21](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/021) is on-point for what you're trying to do here. See `gsub_literal` defined therein.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Scape the slash in the value of `olddescription`:

`olddescription='(1 phrase\/line)';`

Then, you can try this:

`sed -i "s/$olddescription/$newdescription/g" __openerp__.py`

Comment: Note that `olddescription` has a `/` in it. Adding syntactic quotes, while necessary, isn't sufficient to prevent `sed` from getting confused in that scenario.

Comment: Thanks for correcting me @CharlesDuffy. I changed my answer to solve the real issue.

Comment: Test your modified answer: `olddescription='(1 phrase/line)'; newdescription="\\\"$volledigenaam\\\""; sed -e "s/$olddescription/$newdescription/g" </dev/null`. I'm really quite certain it's still wrong, because the thing it's **not** escaping is the `/` in the value of `olddescription`; on GNU `sed`, that test returns the same error the OP initially reports.

Comment: Thanks again! Fixed and retested. I missed the slash in the `olddescription`. Sorry for this.

Comment: Are the literal backslashes before the quotes actually needed? That is to say, if we *only* escaped the one in `olddescription` and made no other changes, would that not fix the OP's issue as well? (This also doesn't help if the value of `$volledigenaam` contains a `/`; since it isn't specified by the OP, an *ideal* answer would cover all possible values).

Comment: You're totally right! Thanks for making me to see it! Answer fixed.

Comment: Thanks guys, worked perfectly!

Comment: The so-called duplicate is overly broad and does not easily answer this simple question.